# How to run a controller's action in whenever's config/schedule

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, whenever

I've never used `whenever` app before. Trying to learn out how to use it to run an action from the controller. Is that possible?

**Controller**

```
class EntriesController < ApplicationController


def index
  @entries = Entry.all
end

def scrape
    require 'open-uri'
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://www.reddit.com/"))

    entries = doc.css('.entry')
    entriesArray = []
    entries.each do |entry|
      title = entry.css('p.title > a').text
      link = entry.css('p.title > a')[0]['href']
      entriesArray << Entry.new({ title: title, link: link })
    end

    if entriesArray.map(&:valid?)
      entriesArray.map(&:save!)
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to entries_url, notice: 'Entries were successfully scraped.' }
      format.json { entriesArray.to_json }
    end
  end

end
```

**Config/schedule.rb**

```
every 1.day, :at => "12:00pm" do 
    runner "Task.scrape"
end
```

Comment: Why is this a Nokogiri question? Because the code mentions it? Only tag when there is a problem, not just because it's mentioned somewhere. What did you try? What happened when you tried? Did it work or fail? If it failed we need to see the error. If it didn't fail why did you ask the question?

Comment: @theTinMan, Ok, thank you for letting me know that I shouldn't have mentioned it. Thought it was a good idea because sometimes things affect each other, and sometimes it's helpful to see the "bigger picture" so to speak. Won't do it again. Only will mention relevant tags pertinent to the question.

Comment: If an error mentioned it then it'd make sense. Code can use many different libraries or gems, way too many to mention, so unless they're specifically involved in the question don't bother.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move your code to separate file and re-use it in schedule.rb and in a controller:

```
# lib/reddit_scrapper.rb
require 'open-uri'

module RedditScrapper
  def self.scrape
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://www.reddit.com/"))

    entries = doc.css('.entry')
    entriesArray = []
    entries.each do |entry|
      title = entry.css('p.title > a').text
      link = entry.css('p.title > a')[0]['href']
      entriesArray << Entry.new({ title: title, link: link })
    end

    if entriesArray.map(&:valid?)
      entriesArray.map(&:save!)
    end
  end
end
```

The controller's code:

```
class EntriesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @entries = Entry.all
  end

  def scrape
    RedditScrapper.scrape

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to entries_url, notice: 'Entries were successfully scraped.' }
      format.json { entriesArray.to_json }
    end
  end
end
```

Whenever task:

```
every 1.day, :at => "12:00pm" do 
  runner "RedditScrapper.scrape"
end
```

Comment: when you say to put it in the `lib`, you meant that alone, not `lib/tasks` correct?

Comment: ok, put it in the `lib` and copied over your whenever task ... how do i make sure it's working? as of now, the front page is displaying the older reddit contents ...

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like it takes in any params. Dont forget that controllers are just Ruby objects:

```
EntriesController.new.scrape
```

Comment: a bit confused by your answer. You're saying that it my runner should be `runner "EntriesController.new.scrape"`?

Comment: @user27307254534534534543675765 Yes, give that a try

Comment: thank you. Just modified it right now. But don't know how to make sure it's working?